# Automate counting the number of occurrences

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I want to know that how many times 'ABCD'(file A) comes in DB (file B). Likewise I want to know about every singe line present in file A against DB. I need an automated command which can ease my work because I have a large amount of data in file A and I want to search it against many databases. I just make the characters bold for understanding.

#### File A

```
ABCD
EFG
HIJKL
MNO
PQRSTU
```

#### File B

> XYZ**ABCD**FORNTUFPSRWSABCFYWSZCFTHBFORTYBJNF**ABCD**D**EFG**ACVRT**EFG**PQRMNOOPQ**EFG**ZXXXYY

#### Desired output:

```
ABCD  2
EFG   3
HIJKL 4567
MNO   0
PQRSTU 7652
```

Comment: It is unclear to me where those counts are supposed to come from.

Comment: Dear Stephen, these counts shows that ABCD comes 1265 times in DB which is file B basically its is comparing two files file A which contain just sequences and file B which is large DB . I hope its clear to you know. So what i want is to find the no. of counts of each line of file A against file B

Comment: Can you edit your post and show a small `File B` and then the Desired Output with that file B?

Comment: I have edited the post kindly acknowledged it. Thank you for your support.

Comment: I do not see 4567 occurrences of HIJKL.  And are these always words separated by `*`

Comment: You said you made the patterns bold, so I assume the `**` in your example isn't actually in your file. Is that correct? If so, why have you accepted an answer that relies on the presence of the `*`? Is your "DB" a single long line and you're looking for specific substrings?

Comment: Answerers: Please read [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/23408)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My suggestion is:

```
IFS=; while read -r word; do printf "%s " $word; grep -o $word b | wc -l; done < a
```

- using `while` we loop into words (file a)
- `printf "%s " $word` : prints the word name, eg: ABCD
- `grep -o $word b | wc -l`: counts and print the number of occurrences

Comment: This is much better than my `bash` version, and more portable,too.

Answer (score 6):

#### Python

`count_patterns.py` script. Should be fairly good for large files. Uses `OrderedDict` to record all patterns from file A provided on command line and searches for them in file B.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from collections import OrderedDict

with open(sys.argv[1]) as pattern_file, open(sys.argv[2]) as data_file:
    patterns = OrderedDict.fromkeys(map(str.strip, pattern_file), 0)

    for line in data_file:
        for p in patterns:
            patterns[p] += line.count(p)

for kv in patterns.items():
    print(*kv)
```

Usage:

```
$ ./count_patterns.py file_A.txt file_B.txt 
ABCD 4
EFG 3
HIJKL 0
MNO 1
PQRSTU 0
```

---

#### Bash approach.

This uses process substitution from `sed` which lets us split file A into newlines at `**`, and use `grep -c` to count number of matched lines.

```
$ cat file_B.txt 
ABCD**FORNTUFPSRWSABCFYWSZCFTHBFORTYBJNF**ABCD**D**EFG**ACVRT**EFG**PQRMNOOPQ**EFG**ZXXXYY
ABCD**FORNTUFPSRWSABCFYWSZCFTHBFORTYBJNF**ABCD

$ cat file_A.txt 
ABCD
EFG
HIJKL
MNO
PQRSTU

$ while IFS= read -r pattern;  do  printf "%s\t" "$pattern";   grep -c "$pattern" < <( sed 's/\*\*/\n/g' file_B.txt ); done  < file_A.txt 
ABCD    4
EFG 3
HIJKL   0
MNO 1
PQRSTU  0
```

Not the best way to do it, probably not suitable for large files, but works. Wouldn't recommend using the bash method, but if data set isn't large, it will work.

Answer (score 5):

### Bash

Using Bash's associative [arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -eu
declare -A patterns

while IFS= read -r p; do
    patterns["$p"]=0
done < "$1"

while IFS='*' read -ra l; do
    for r in "${l[@]}"; do
        if [ -n "$r" ] && [ -v patterns["$r"] ]; then
            patterns[$r]=$((${patterns["$r"]} + 1))
        fi
    done
done < "$2"

for p in "${!patterns[@]}"; do
    printf '%s\t%u\n' "$p" "${patterns["$p"]}"
done
```

Usage:

```
bash count-patterns.sh pattern-list.txt word-list.txt
```

### Python 3

Using a custom dictionary class and functional style data processing:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys, itertools, collections

class MyCounter(collections.UserDict):
    def __init__(self, _dict):
        self.data = _dict

    def update(self, iterable):
        for key in iterable:
            self.data[key] += 1

with open(sys.argv[1]) as pattern_file:
    patterns = MyCounter({ s.rstrip('\n'): 0 for s in pattern_file })

with open(sys.argv[2]) as wordlist_file:
    patterns.update(filter(patterns.__contains__,
        itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(
            lambda s: s.rstrip('\n').split('**'), wordlist_file))))

for p in patterns.items():
    print(*p, sep='\t')
```

Usage:

```
python3 count-patterns.py pattern-list.txt word-list.txt
```

### C++

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

namespace std
{
    template <class Ch, class Tr, class K, class V, class H, class Eq>
    basic_ostream<Ch,Tr> &operator<<( basic_ostream<Ch,Tr> &os,
        const std::unordered_map<K,V,H,Eq> &m )
    {
        for (const typename std::unordered_map<K,V,H,Eq>::value_type &i: m)
            os << i.first << '\t' << i.second << '\n';
        return os.flush();
    }
}

template <class Key, class Hash = std::hash<Key>, class Equal = std::equal_to<Key>>
class counter :
    public std::unordered_map<Key, std::size_t, Hash, Equal>
{
private:
    typedef std::unordered_map<Key, std::size_t, Hash, Equal> _base;

public:
    void update_existing( const Key &k, std::size_t count = 1 )
    {
        const typename _base::iterator match = this->find(k);
        if (match != this->end())
            match->second += count;
    }
};

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <PATTERN-FILE> <WORDLIST-FILE>" << std::endl;
        return 2;
    }

    counter<std::string> patterns;
    std::string buf;
    {
        std::ifstream pattern_file(argv[1]);
        while (pattern_file.good() && !std::getline(pattern_file, buf).fail())
            patterns.emplace(std::move(buf), 0);
    }

    if (!patterns.empty())
    {
        std::ifstream wordlist_file(argv[2]);
        while (wordlist_file.good() && !std::getline(wordlist_file, buf).fail())
        {
            static const char delim[] = {'*', '*'};
            std::size_t offset = 0, p = 0;
            while ((p = buf.find(delim, offset, sizeof(delim))) != std::string::npos)
            {
                patterns.update_existing(buf.substr(offset, p - offset));
                offset = p + sizeof(delim);
            }
            patterns.update_existing(buf.erase(0, offset));
        }
    }

    std::cout << patterns;
}
```

Compile with:

```
c++ -std=c++11 -o count-patterns count-patterns.cpp
```

Usage:

```
./count-patterns pattern-list.txt word-list.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an `awk` program that should do what you are after:

#### Code:

```
BEGIN {FS="*"}
FNR==NR {a[$0]=0; next}
{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i in a) a[$i]++}
END {
    for (i in a) {
        print i, a[i]
    }
}
```

#### How?

1. Set the field seperaotr to `*`
2. `FNR==NR {a[$0]=0; next}` loads the words to match into array `a`
3. For each line, test and increment if the field between `*`'s is in `a`
4. Print `a` in the `END` block

#### Run with:

```
awk -f test.awk fileA DB
```

#### Results:

```
ABCD 2
HIJKL 0
EFG 3
MNO 0
PQRSTU 0
```